# Unable to reset Widow on beforeunload events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two functions one to set `beforeunload` and another to remove it as:

```
function setOnBeforeLoad(){
    console.log('setOnBeforeLoad');
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
        return 'abc';
    });
}
function removeOnBeforeLoad(){
    console.log('removeOnBeforeLoad');
    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
            // return undefined;
            // return null;
    });
}
```

Once, the `onbeforeload` event is added, I am unable to remove it. So, its preventing reload unnecessarily.

I have tried by returning nothing, `undefined` and `null`. However, nothing seems working. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [jQuery namespaces](https://acdcjunior.github.io/jquery-creating-specific-event-and-removing-it-only.html) (and `.off()` to remove the event) for that:

```
function setOnBeforeLoad(){
    console.log('setOnBeforeLoad');
    $(window).on('beforeunload.somenamespace', function(){
        return 'abc';
    });
}
function removeOnBeforeLoad(){
    console.log('removeOnBeforeLoad');
    $(window).off('beforeunload.somenamespace');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(window).off('beforeunload')
```